# True or false proposition about double integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Indicate whether the following proposition is true or false justifying the answer:

"For every continuous function $f(x,y)$ it is carried out that $$\int_1^2\int_1^xf(x,y)dydx=\int_1^2\int_y^2 f(x,y)dxdy"$$

Comment: Try drawing a sketch of the domains of integration.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: As long as Fubini's theorem applies, the statement is correct.